# Android Qの端末で端末内の写真を表示しようとするとエラーが発生してしまう

Tags: android

AndroidのアプリでAndroid Q以前の端末では問題がなかったのですが、Android Qの端末にて端末内の写真を表示しようとすると下記のエラーが発生してしまう事象で困っております。

```
E/TEST: ERROR
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column CAST(STRFTIME('%Y%m%d', datetaken / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS INTEGER) AS format_date_taken
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:423)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:944)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:880)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:81)
        at jp.app.myapp.upload.multi.cameraroll.HeaderDataCursorLoader.loadInBackground(HeaderDataCursorLoader.java:64)
        at jp.app.myapp.upload.multi.cameraroll.HeaderDataCursorLoader.loadInBackground(HeaderDataCursorLoader.java:21)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:307)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:60)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:48)
        at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:141)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

再現ソースコードは下記になります。

```
public class HeaderDataCursorLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<HeaderDataCursor> {
    public HeaderDataCursor loadInBackground() {
        try {
            String columnName = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN;
            String[] projection = new String[]{
                    BaseColumns._ID,
                    "CAST(STRFTIME('%Y%m%d', " + columnName + " / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS INTEGER) AS format_date_taken",
                    columnName
            };
            Cursor dataCursor = android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat.query(
                    getContext().getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            android.util.Log.e("TEST", "ERROR", e);
        }
    }
}
```

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column CAST(STRFTIME('%Y%m%d', datetaken / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS INTEGER) AS format_date_taken`とあったので、この部分を削除すると表示はされるのですが、なぜそうなってしまうのかの原因がわからずに困っております。
※ このCASTした値を、後で使いたいため。

[こちらのサイト](https://medium.com/@star_zero/android-q%E3%81%AEscoped-storage%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4-afe41cde9f35)に記載されているように、Android Qからストレージにアクセスする方法が変更されているとのことなのですが、AndroidManifestに`requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`を追加しても同様のエラーが出てしまっているので、根本解決をしたいと思っているのですが、どのように修正をすればよいのかがわからずに困っております。

解決方法をご教授して頂きますと幸いでございます。
※ 可能であれば、APIレベルはあげずに対応が出来れば助かります。。

何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。

環境

- Android Studio3.5
- compileSdkVersion = 28
- buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
- targetSdkVersion = 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Qでは該当箇所にカラム名そのものしかうけつけなくなっているようですね。断言はできませんが、リグレッションの可能性が高いです。APIドキュメントには任意のSQLが記述できるとは書いていないので、仕様通りともとれます。コード側でSQLと同等の整形処理を行うように修正するのがよいかと思われます

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContentResolverCompat

Comment: やはりコード側で修正するのが良さそうですよね。ご回答ありがとうございました。